# Is there a service with a public domain name that automatically resolves to an arbitrary IP address?

Tags: dns

I can swear I saw something like that a few weeks ago, but I cannot remember the name.

I'm looking for a public domain name that would automatically resolve subnames to the corresponding, arbitrary IP address. For instance, `127.0.0.2.blah.com` would resolve to a single `A` record to `127.0.0.2`.

I'm aware of the security implications. I'd like to have that for quick and dirty security testing scenarios, where I want to force-feed an IP address to software that will only accept a DNS name.

I'm also aware I could set it up myself. But I'm sure someone has done it already.

Comment: Why dont you just put it in /etc/hosts (or C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts)?

Comment: @Virsacer because I'm not admin on the machine that runs the target software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going out on a limb, I am guessing you mean something like [xip.io (Wayback Machine)](https://web.archive.org/web/20210428113017/http://xip.io/).

Unfortunately, xip.io seems to have died in mid-2021. However, you may want to investigate alternatives such as [nip.io](https://nip.io/) or [sslip.io](https://sslip.io/).